# openerp: Set default value for one2many field

Tags: default, odoo, one-to-many

I need to set default value for one2many field. I tried it with a function in _defaults but my function doesn't get called.

Here is my code:

Field:

```
'tax_invoice_line_ids': fields.one2many('account.tax.line', 'tax_id', 'Tax Invoice', domain=[('apply_on','=','invoice')]),
```

_defaults:

```
_defaults = {
    'tax_invoice_line_ids': _invoice_line_default,
    }
```

_invoice_line_default:

```
def _invoice_line_default(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    print "\n\ncame here..........................................."
    return True
```

am i missing something?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error in server log????

Comment: No i m not getting any error. But the print placed inside _invoice_line_default doesn't print anything. Means the function doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is not loading, then first add a char field and use the _defaults to load its value to the field. if its working and your function in the _defaults to load data to one2many is still not calling you then you can use the alternate solutions like use the default_get function, or use the onchange function of any required field to load the data to the one2many..When using onchange function you have to unlink the previous values in the one2many list before loading the new values

Comment: Done with Default_get. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have the field tax_invoice_line_ids in the view.

Comment: <group colspan="7" name="invoice">
    <field name="tax_invoice_line_ids" context="   {'default_apply_on':'invoice'}" nolabel="1"/>
</group>

Comment: Which view are you inheriting?

Comment: It doesn't inherit any view.

Comment: <record id="view_tax_form" model="ir.ui.view">

            <field name="name">account.tax.form</field>

            <field name="model">account.tax</field>

            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <form string="Account Tax" version="7.0">

                </form>

            </field>

        </record>

Comment: where you able to view the field in the view?

Comment: the whole view is too long and take too much time to understand so i have just pasted view(comment6) and field inside it(comment3).